# Open Multiple URLS with firefox in private mode using powershell

Tags: powershell, url, firefox

I am trying a script to make firefox open 1 private window with multiple URLs however the problem is if I have firefox open and run that script it opens 1 URL in private windows then opens another private window and opens the rest of the URLs

If I have Firefox closed and run that script it runs as expected and only 1 private window opens opening all URLs in different tabs

I tried that same script with google chrome and it works as expected wether I have chrome open or not so am assuming it is something related to firefox setting that I don't know about

```
$urls = @("https://google.com/","https://www.youtube.com/","https://www.facebook.com")

foreach($url in $urls){

    start "C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe" -ArgumentList @( '-private-window' , $url)
}
```

I also tried the code in the following form:

```
start "C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe" -ArgumentList @( '-private-window' , 'https://google.com/')

start "C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe" -ArgumentList @( '-private-window' , 'https://facebook.com/')

start "C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe" -ArgumentList @( '-private-window' , 'https://youtube.com/')
```

Both codes do the same thing and I get the same results.

What I want is to open 1 private window regardless of how many tabs or windows I have open of firefox and open the URLs in the script in just this 1 private window.

Note: the above code works as expected in chrome so the issue is probably with firefox something needs to be changed am not sure what.

Comment: Unable to reproduce ur issue. All URLs open in the same private window for me. I was testing with Firefox v68.0. Would it be possible you are running into this issue because you are using a developer edition?

Comment: I just tested with firefox 68.0 same issue occurs if i have no windows open of firefox it works however if i have a window open of firefox and run it it opens 2 private windows not 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was finally able to reproduce your issue to some extent. If I run ur script 'as is' it would open 3 tabs in a private window. If I ran it again, it would add new tabs to that existing window.

Then I ran ur script with one normal window open and I think I saw your issue here. 2 private windows opened, one with 2 tabs and one with 1. The one with 2 tabs had one of the tab blank. so one of the URLs didnt open as expected.

On repetition, I figured it was not always the same URL that got "foxblocked" lol. So I added a delay in the `foreach` loop which seems to have done away with the issue I was seeing. Perhaps `firefox.exe` is not able to handle requests as fast as we were serving it.

```
$urls = @("https://google.com/","https://www.youtube.com/","https://www.facebook.com")

foreach($url in $urls){

    start "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -ArgumentList @( '-private-window' , $url)
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```